# Asymptotic equivalence between a logarithm-type function on the natural numbers and the natural logarithm

Tags: logarithms, asymptotics

I have been taking a look at an analogue of the logarithm defined only on the positive integers, such that:
$f(1)=1$, 
$f(p) = 1 + f(p-1)$ for prime p, 
$f(mn) = f(m) + f(n)$ for m, n integers greater than 1.

I have observed that $f(n)$ is approximately equal to $log(n^3)$, where $log$ is the natural logarithm.How could one go about proving that these two functions are indeed asymptotic?

Comment: Rough asymptotics: (1) $f$ is monotone increasing. (2) $f(2^{n+1}) = (n+1)f(2) = 2(n+1)$, $f(2^{n}) = nf(2) = 2n$. So $f(k)$ is sandwiched between $2\lfloor \log_2 k\rfloor$ and $2\lceil \log_2 k\rceil$.

Comment: The OEIS sequence [A061373](http://oeis.org/A061373)  has a link to an article by Reyna (in Spanish) with some asymptotics.

Comment: I think closer to $f(n) \approx 3.2 \log(n)$ but the ratio does not seem to approach a limit. There is a lot of scatter in interval  $(2.8,3.5)$.

Comment: @Somos The Spanish article you link shows it's between $\frac{3}{\log 3}\log n$  and $\frac{3}{\log 2}\log n$ (Corolario 9).